# How do I best define an REST endpoint with a verb in it?

Tags: rest

I need to define an end-point for an action the back-end is supposed to take: format the device.

The end-point I have come up with is:

```
POST /device/{deviceId}/format
```

without any body.

This, doesn't look RESTful though. Or is it?

Is there any alternative for this ? How can I make it RESTful?

Comment: In a REST architecture the spelling of the URI isn't of relevance. What's more important is, how a client learns about the possibilities it has from its current state onwards. Here, link relations may indicate a client that a URI will serve a certain purpose. On relying on link relations and just using the accompanied URI provided by the server you allow the server to change its URI scheme any time it wants to without actually breaking your client implementation.

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URI.

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stop
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrastinate

All of these identifiers work *fine*.  The machines don't care, because they aren't trying to extract semantic information from the identifier.  General-purpose clients consider the URI to be opaque (aside from certain purely mechanical concerns permitted by RFC 3986).

> This, doesn't look RESTful though. Or is it?

It can be fine, there might be better choices.  Caching is a very important idea in REST, and if you expect that a successful POST request will change one of the representations that the client may have cached, then you will want to think about how to communicate to the client that some cache entries need to be [invalidated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

Another way of expressing the same idea; you might imagine that our API is a collection of objects.  What you are trying do here is send a `format` message to the device.  A simple spelling of this might look like

```
Resource(/device/{deviceId}).FORMAT()
```

But our problem is that `FORMAT` isn't part of the uniform interface currently defined by HTTP; and trying to come up with semantics for FORMAT that are consistent across all resources isn't worth the bother.

What's are alternative?  [It's okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

```
Resource(/device/{deviceId}).POST()
```

and that works fine.  Of course, sometimes we have more than one action that isn't worth standardizing.  How do we discriminate between them?

```
Resource(/device/{deviceId}).POST(format)
```

The general purpose components route the request to your post handler, then your bespoke code interrogates the request and forward it to the module in your code that specializes in handling formatting requests.